# H2 console can't access jbdc database

Tags: h2

I've been looking all around but cannot find a solution to my problem.

I have a H2 database managed by hybernate and JPA. The specified address in persistence.xml is : jdbc:h2:./data/repository.

I can get it in the Console H2, when I enter in the console with that same address, I just can't see any tables... but they exist since I can get them from my java application.

Thank's for your help, always appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used a path relative to the current working directory. But the current working directory depends on where and how you start your application.
Use an absolute path instead of a relative one:

```
jdbc:h2:/data/repository
```

or relative to the current user home directory:

```
jdbc:h2:~/data/repository
```